# Creating directory entry object in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a global variable for director entry object using `cordova-plugin-file` (file plugin of cordova)

You can read [Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#sample-create-files-and-directories-write-read-and-append-files-) here.

This is what I am trying to do :

```
 var dirEntry ; //global variable
function init()
{
    console.log('inside init()');
     dirEntry = window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, createDirEntry, onErrorResolveURL);
}

function createDirEntry(dir){
    console.log('file system open: ' + dir.name);
    console.log('dir : '+dir);
    return dir; //to be stored inside dirEntry
}

function checkIfExists(fileName){ //this is where error is arising

dirEntry.getFile(fileName,{create:false, exclusive:false}, readFile, function (fileName){
    console.log('File checkIfExistError : '+error.code);
    createFile(dirEntry, filename,true);
});
}
```

In console error pops that `Cannot read getFile of undefined`pointing towards `dirEntry`.

When I check value of `dirEntry` on console it shows `undefined`.
Same is applicable for `dir` when I check inside its function.

Comment: @NullPointer can you help with this?

Comment: Do you call init before calling checkIfExists?

Comment: Init is like a main function, it will be always called. I also tried assigning return value of `createDirEntry` to some other variable from console, but it didn't worked out either.